# How to import notebooks .py inside the Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to use some functions that are contained in other python modules/notebooks (`.py`) in a google colab notebook.

With the google colab notebook open, I went to index >> files >> upload and uploaded the file `EOS.py`. However, when I do `import EOS` or `from EOS import set_eos` it gives an error. What should I change so that the call of a mudlo or external function of a mutale is correct?

[image]

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the files tab?

Comment: Of course :) I already added

Comment: It looks like you uploaded the file the right way and it's on the correct path, I guess the problem will be in the `EOS.py` file, make sure that this file doesn't run any code when you import it.

Comment: ex. make sure that you are not executing the `set_eos` function, like `set_eos('apr.dat')`